# Facebook access token changes by app reinstall

Tags: android, facebook, cocos2d-x, facebook-access-token

I'm using Facebook access token to get user info for our mobile game. The Android app gets the token from Facebook, the respective Facebook app is installed on user's Facebook account. My problem is that the Facebook access token is changed every single time when i uninstall/reinstall the Android app. How to get a consistent access token? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course removing the app causes the access token to become invalid – otherwise apps could still go on using my token after I removed the app. But how is this a problem? If the user logs in to your app again after they removed it, you will get a new access token – so use that to perform whatever requests you are making.

Comment: Exactly! why do you need it to be constant? It acts like a session, so its not meant to be a constant, your code should not be dependent on the access token.

Comment: @CBroe i'm using a 3rd party web service leaderboards, achievements etc. Users are stored in there. And changing the pasword, i mean updating it with the new token(token is used as the password here) requires the old password. And i'm unable to get the old password.

Comment: Well that’s something you should clarify with that 3rd party service provider then. If they chose to implement it that way, there isn’t much we can do about that.